# Extending props across multiple React HOCs

Tags: reactjs, typescript, types, higher-order-functions, higher-order-components

I'm a little new to Typescript and confused on how to do this.
I have a React component with props which looks like:

```
type ComponentProps = {
   prop1: any,
   prop2: any
} & React.HTMLAttributes<HTMLDivElement>

const Component = ({
   prop1,
   prop2,
   ...props
): ComponentProps} => {
   console.log(prop1,  prop2)
   return (
      <div {...props}>
         {props.children}
      </div>
   )
}
```

I want the component to pass through two HOCs, which essentially add a prop each:

```
function FirstHOC<T>(Component: React.ComponentType<T>) {
  return (props: T & { newProp1: any }) => 
     <Component
         {...props}
         newProp1={props.newProp1}
      />
}
function SecondHOC<T>(Component: React.ComponentType<T>) {
   return (props: T & { newProp2: any }) =>
      <Component
         {...props}
         newProp2={props.newProp2}
      />
}
```

and then finalize it with something like

```
export default MyComponent = FirstHOC<ComponentProps>(SecondHOC<ComponentProps>(Component))
```

such that I can use the component like

```
<MyComponent
   prop1="1"
   prop2="2"
   newProp1="3"
   newProp2="4"
/>
```

with no type errors. Currently, I am doing essentially what I've written here, but only the inner HOC is having its props passed down. FirstHOC's `newProp1`, in my example, is giving me a type error. `newProp2` is not. How could I correctly chain HOCs and attach props along the way?

Comment: Why do you need to do this? How is the original component supposed to use the new props, if it doesn't expect or know what the new props are?

Comment: The above code is very simplified. I am building UI components and want to attach a few props universally to all of them. For instance, one of my HOCs uses Emotion to add a prop called css that allows in-line styling. Making an HOC-generator-thingy like above is the alternative to going into each component and manually adding Emotion logic. In other words, the Component won't need the props directly, but the end-user would be able to use them.